# media-heading at the bottom of the image?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to create a horizontal list of images and put image-heading under the image (instead of above it). Is that possible with Bootstrap 3? (Didn't see anything related to that in the docs)

```
<h5 class="media-heading pull-left">One</h5>
<img class="media-object pull-left" src="{% static "/img/one.jpg" %}" alt="..." />
<h5 class="media-heading pull-left">Two</h5>
<img class="media-object pull-left" src="{% static "/img/two.jpg" %}" alt="..." />
<h5 class="media-heading pull-left">Three</h5>
<img class="media-object pull-left" src="{% static "/img/three.jpg" %}" alt="..." />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<div class="thumbnail">
      <a href="/w3images/fjords.jpg">
        <img src="/w3images/fjords.jpg" alt="Fjords" style="width:100%">
        <div class="caption">
          <p>Lorem ipsum...</p>
        </div>
      </a>
    </div>
```

Comment: Wow - I never knew about [thumbnails](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/components/#thumbnails) in bootstrap (or perhaps thought of them to be meant only for mini (iconic) images)

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```css
div {
    width: 100px;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;

}

img {
    width: 100%;
}

h5 {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -20px;
    width: 100%;
    margin:0;
    text-align: center;
    background: #CCC;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div>
    <h5 class="media-heading pull-left">One</h5>
    <img class="media-object pull-left" src="http://justcuteanimals.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/10/baby-bear-pictures-cute-animal-pics.jpg" alt="..." />
</div>
<div>
    <h5 class="media-heading pull-left">Two</h5>
    <img class="media-object pull-left" src="http://justcuteanimals.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/10/baby-bear-pictures-cute-animal-pics.jpg" alt="..." />
</div>
<div>
    <h5 class="media-heading pull-left">Three</h5>
     <img class="media-object pull-left" src="http://justcuteanimals.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/10/baby-bear-pictures-cute-animal-pics.jpg" alt="..." />  
</div>
```